# Is there a way to scrub a value for a specific property?

Tags: verify, verify-tests

Apologies if this is documented somewhere, but I was unable to find it.

I have this nested `shortId` field

```json
{ 
  ...
  "positions" 
    [ 
      { 
        ....
        "shortId": ABC123 
      },  
    ] 
}
```

I need to scrub it the same way guids are scrubbed.  Looking through the code, it looks like the scrubbers are based around detecting the format of the current value.  Is there a way to detect if the value can be scrubbed based on the property name?

Cheers,
Drew

[edit]
So far, it looks like I'll need to create a new scrubber that parses the entire StringBuilder to identify the properties.  I'm wondering if someone has already done this or if I need to write it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/VerifyTests/Verify/blob/main/docs/serializer-settings.md#scrub-member-by-name

```
[Fact]
public Task ScrubMemberByNameFluent()
{
    var target = new IgnoreExplicitTarget
    {
        Include = "Value",
        Field = "Value",
        Property = "Value",
        PropertyByName = "Value"
    };
    return Verify(target)
        // For all types
        .ScrubMember("PropertyByName")
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the ScrubMember method.  I looked on the object returned from Verfiy and in VerifySettings.  I can see IgnoreMember which is what we're currently using, but ScrubMember would be more usufle.  We're currently using v 17.10.2.  I tried upgrading to v19 but still didn't see ScrubMember